# How can I change the format of numbers

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I want to change the data to this format. Example: 1.000,00 and the result that appears from the data is 1,000.00

I used the stringFormat but it is not working for this format 1.000,00

```
<Label Text="{Binding paymentAmount, StringFormat='{0:n}'}" TextColor="White" Font="14" HorizontalOptions="EndAndExpand" VerticalOptions="EndAndExpand" />
```

Comment: What locale is the device set to?

Comment: Locale settings will change the decimal sign, but SO desired result is more like a custom formatting (`.` and `,` are present).

Comment: en_Us-English(United states) @Neil

Comment: "1,000.00" is correct for en-us.  The format you require is more like Spanish/Mexican ?  If that is the case, either set the locale in code, or trust the user has their device configured correctly.

Comment: I changed the location of the device and it worked. Thank you @Neil

Comment: But if I want the format to be fixed so 1000.00 regardless of location @Neil

Comment: @Robin's answer is correct, but you should really let the user decide how they want their numbers formatted, rather than be forced into a specific way

Answer (score 2):

You appear to be after a European format, so this should work:

```
Text="{Binding paymentAmount, StringFormat={}{0:n}, ConverterCulture=de-DE}"
```

Although, as @Neil says, it's better to let it default to the user's culture.

Comment: Is not working, what I really want is to put with European standard as standard @Robin